# Run two Kotlin coroutines inside coroutine in parallel

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have two suspend functions:

```
suspend fun sendData() : Boolean 

suspend fun awaitAcknowledge() : Boolean
```

and I want to wrap them in a third suspend function in which they should be executed in parallel and I want to calculate the final result by having both return values:

```
suspend fun sendDataAndAwaitAcknowledge() : Boolean {
    // TODO execute both in parallel and compare both results
}
```

However, if I write it like that,

```
suspend fun sendDataAndAwaitAcknowledge() : Boolean {
    val sendResult = sendData()
    val receiveAck = awaitAcknowledge()
}
```

the functions will be executed in a serial order, which will not work in my case.

Coming from RxJava, I would like to achieve something like the `zip` operator:

```
Single.zip(awaitAcknowledge(), sendData(), {receiveAck, sendResult -> ...})
```

How can I do this with `Coroutines`?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use `awaitAll` for that purpose:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

suspend fun sendDataAndAwaitAcknowledge() = coroutineScope {
    awaitAll(async {
        awaitAcknowledge()
    }, async {
        sendData()
    })
}

fun sendData() = true

fun awaitAcknowledge() = false

fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        println(sendDataAndAwaitAcknowledge()) // [false, true]
    }
}
```

Comment: It is possible to execute all functions at the same time without a milliseconds delay?

Answer (score 13):

This is the general pattern:

```kotlin
suspend fun sendDataAndAwaitAck() = coroutineScope {
  val one = async { sendData() }
  val two = async { awaitAck() }
  println("The result is ${one.await()}, ${two.await()}")
}
```

The two suspending functions (`sendData` and `awaitAck`) are called from within another suspending function (`sendDataAndAwaitAck`). They could potentially run in parallel, depending on the environment and CPU setup. The outer suspending function will wait for the two inner functions to finish their tasks before proceeding.

**Note 1**: `async` is available only in a Coroutine Scope.

**Note 2**: if you don't want the whole scope to fail when one of the child coroutines fails, you should use `supervisorScope` instead.

Comment: you cannot just use `async`. You need coroutine scope for it

Comment: @AndreiTanana check the link. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/composing-suspending-functions.html

Comment: this is the full code of this example https://github.com/kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-core/jvm/test/guide/example-compose-02.kt it uses `runBlocking` scope

Comment: Hmm, when I try to implement in this way, I get `unresolved reference` on the `async` keyword. However, I don't get an import suggestion from Android Studio.

Comment: The `async` being used here is a static import from `GlobalScope`, which is not a great thing to use. Async should be launched off of a more granular coroutine scope.