# Android: kotlin coroutine background task

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a method

```
fun refrehList() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        myData.value = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            summaryRepository.getSummaries(true)
        }
        allData.value = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            SummaryRepository.getSummaries(false)
        }
    }
}
```

Is this correct way of using coroutine. Is the DB operation happening in the background scope

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Room, its documentation states the following:

> You can add the suspend Kotlin keyword to your DAO methods to make
>   them asynchronous using Kotlin coroutines functionality. This ensures
>   that they cannot be executed on the main thread.

So you will be safe calling your repository inside the `viewModelScope` without changing context.

You can find that Room's documentation section [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#kotlin-coroutines).

Comment: I have those methods as @Transaction. So does that mean I can just call them likefun refrehList() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        myData.value =
            summaryRepository.getSummaries(true)
        
        allData.value =
            SummaryRepository.getSummaries(false)
        
    }
}

Comment: @png Sure, you can see one of the examples in the link I provided is a transaction and it actually states the following: ***This guidance also applies to DAO methods annotated with `@Transaction`. You can use this feature to build suspending database methods out of other DAO methods. These methods then run in a single database transaction.***

Answer (score 3):

Yes this code will run on separate thread but one after another. Also you should be using `Dispatchers.IO` for database calls instead of `Dispatchers.Default`  See [Io vs Default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59039991/difference-between-usage-of-dispatcher-io-and-default).

```
viewModelScope.launch {
        myData.value = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
           Log.e("thread1", Thread.currentThread().name)
            summaryRepository.getSummaries(true)
        }
         Log.e("thread2", Thread.currentThread().name)
        allData.value = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
           Log.e("thread3", Thread.currentThread().name)
            SummaryRepository.getSummaries(false)
        }
    }
```

This will print something like :-

```
E/thread: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
E/thread2: main
E/thread3: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
```

If you want to run those co-routine in parallel you can use [`async-await`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57457079/run-two-kotlin-coroutines-inside-coroutine-in-parallel) .